# What is the best approah to insert large records return from webservice in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Using Async-based Webservice and Async framework in WinRT (Win8) to get a large recordsets(1000 to 5000) from a remote Ms SQL Server.

I want to know :

1) Which is the best approach to handle to insert large recordsets into SQLite?
2) Using RollBack transaction will start all over again if there is connection error. The below method will insert whatever and I can update the data later if the records are not complete. Is this a good approach?
3) Any better way to enhance my below solution?

```
This foreach statement to handle 
each reords in returned result which returned from Async-Based WebService:

foreach (WebServiceList _List in IList)
   {      

     InsertNewItems(_List.No, _List.Description, _List.Unit_Price, _List.Base_Unit_of_Measure);

   }


 private void InsertNewItems(string ItemNo, string ItemName, decimal ItemPrice, string ItemBUoM)
 {

    var existingItem = (db2.Table().Where(c => c.No == ItemNo)).SingleOrDefault();

    if (existingItem != null)
    {
      existingItem.No = ItemNo;
      existingItem.Description = ItemName;
      existingItem.Unit_Price = ItemPrice;
      existingItem.BaseUnitofMeasure = ItemBUoM;

      int success = db2.Update(existingItem);

      }
      else
      {
        int success = db2.Insert(new Item()
         {
           No = ItemNo,                          
           Description = ItemName,
           Unit_Price = ItemPrice,                       
           Base_Unit_of_Measure = ItemBUoM     

         });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RunInTransaction` from [sqlite-net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net). The documentation for it says,

> Executes action within a (possibly nested) transaction by wrapping it
>   in a SAVEPOINT. If an exception occurs the whole transaction is rolled
>   back, not just the current savepoint. The exception is rethrown.

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
{
    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        db.InsertOrReplace(MyObj);
    });
}
```

[Wiki article](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/Transactions) for Transactions at GitHub

Comment: Bulk inserts usually disable transactions though.

Comment: Will this statement Using( var db=new SQLiteConnection() ) stop SQLite once error encountered. Shoul I declare SQLite as a Global var so that I can keep running it even error encountered?

Answer (score 0):

The most important performance aspect for bulk inserts is to use a single transaction. If you want to handle aborts, I suggest that you feed the data in sufficiently large parts and restart from that point on next time. An SQL transaction either finishes completely or rolls back completely, so unless the input data changes between two runs, there should be no need to do an insert-or-update.

See, for example, [here](http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/) for a discussion of SQLite bulk insert performance using different methods.